using a 2d matrix as a feature input to LSTM / RNN models
i am building an LSTM model to predict the combination of items that will be sold at a store level on a daily basis. Please note, this is an exploratory model and i have a good idea about the correlation between SKUs / products of different types. The input features will include different features of each SKU as rows of the matrix ( so columns will be feature and row will be SKU ID ). The output of this model will be a 1D vector of size N ( where N is number of SKUs ) and the label ( GT ) will provide a % breakup of the daily sale. Now i also understand that using the output of a softmax activation does NOT directly translate to percentages but all i need is a ballpark estimate ( and i can also use KL divergence loss instead since all we need is the distribution of the sales to match up to prediction )
so the major question is how do i transform this 2d matrix into a 1d feature vector ? my dumb idea is to simply flatten it using the same order ( for e.g. SKU1-SKU2- etc ..which of course will have problems with missing sales for a particular day and will be a vector of 0's ) and since, during inference i am aware of this order, i will be using the same. Whenever new SKUs are introduced i will simply have to retrain the model from scratch using the new order.
Like i said, the above is just a first pass so any opinions, pointers will be deeply appreciated (across all time steps :P)

You can build a custom LSTM architecture that has multiple branches, each for a specific SKU. This can be done using Pytorch or Keras Functional API If the SKUs have correlations, you can also merge these branches in order to help the model gain some knowledge to make shared features in the center of the architecture. In the output, you can separate these branches once again for each SKU. An example code using Keras:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
timesteps = 10
features = 5

# Define the number of products or SKUs (branches)
num_products = 3

# Create input layers for each product
inputs = [Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name=f'input_{i}') for i in range(num_products)]

# Create LSTM layers for each product branch
lstm_layers = [LSTM(64, return_sequences=False, name=f'lstm_{i}')(input_layer) for i, input_layer in enumerate(inputs)]

# Merge the branches
merged = concatenate(lstm_layers, name='concatenate')

# Add dense layers for shared learning
shared_dense = Dense(64, activation='relu', name='shared_dense_1')(merged)
shared_dense = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='shared_dense_2')(shared_dense)

# Separate the branches for output
outputs = [Dense(1, activation='linear', name=f'output_{i}')(shared_dense) for i in range(num_products)]

# Define the model
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Print the model summary
model.summary()


omg .. this is quite clever ! let me try this out and update the thread

also, is this the same as having parallel LSTM layers , each layer taking in one of the features and then concatenating their hidden states and then passing it to the final classification layer ? either which ways can we use similar architecture for LSTM layers stacked on top of each other ?

Yes, that is possible to use branches of stacked LSTM. But I would try simpler models first. and when facing underfitting, I would use more complicated architectures. As a matter of fact, I recommend using XGBoost for almost all tabular problems. You should make your dataset tidy by creating lagged features.
